# I am not getting console logged my state change by one of the reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, loader

When I am dispatching an action of the loader, the reducer is changing the state when I see in redux logger but it is not console logged in the line next to when I have dispatched the action to change the state.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loader} from "../../actions/loaderAction";
import './Loader.css';
function LoaderPage(props) {
let [showloader,setshowloader] = useState(0);

const testfunc = ()=>{
    props.loader(true);
    console.log(props.Loader);
}
useEffect(()=>{
    testfunc();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
},[]);
return (
    <>
    {showloader
    ?
    <div className="loader-comp">
        <div className="animated yt-loader"></div>
        <div className="mask"></div>
    </div>
    :
    ""
    }
    </>
)
}


const mapStateToProps= (state) => (
{
    Loader:state.Loader
}
)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
 loader
})(LoaderPage);
```

I know reducer returns new state asynchronously, so when I should use console.log for props.Loader
Any help or suggestion is valuable.

Comment: You're only calling the function when the component is mounted (at which point I assume `props.Loader` hasn't yet updated). You never call `testfunc()` again.

Comment: assuming the action updates `Loader` redux state, simply move the `console.log` outside the function. Your component should rerender when the prop changes and log the new value. Also, if you don't call `props.loader` elsewhere, move it inside your `useEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an empty array as second argument to `useEffect` means the code will only execute on mount. And your log doesn't reflect because state update is not sync.

You want log to be executed everytime on `Loader` changes. Remove your `console.log` from your function. Create another `useEffect` to log your `Loader` and  pass `Loader` to array, which means your code will execute on `Loader` changes:

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(props.Loader);
  },[props.Loader]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redux dev tools extension instead of console.log to view and manage your state. It is so simple to use and perfectly built

Answer (score -1):

try using callback pattern

```
const callbackFunction = () =>  console.log("Some code");

const loader = (option = {}) => {
        if(option.cb){
                option.cb();
        }
};

const option = {};
option.cb = callbackFunction;

loader(option);
```